# HTTP Post from Meteor Server does not work - syntax problems?

Tags: meteor, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use Meteor's HTTP.call POST method in order to issue a Cypher query via the Neo4j REST transaction point. However, the Cypher logs give me errors. Advice on how to remedy the suspected syntax issues will be appreciated:

```
HTTP.call('POST', 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher',
    {headers:{"Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    query: "MATCH (n:unit) RETURN n LIMIT 25"},
    function (error, result) {
    // callback function here, not shown for brevity...
});
```

This is the typical error message in the Neo4j console:

"POST /db/data/cypher?MATCH%20(n:unit)%20RETURN%20n%20LIMIT%2025 HTTP/1.1" 400 469 "-" "-"

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: I have received a mix of 500 and 400 messages, I've edited the answer to show the current error codes.

Comment: I seem to be making some headway...the Meteor console now shows that the query parameter was missing, so I've nested the query inside of a parameter Object and I'm getting some kind of response...

Comment: It looks to me that you are adding the query to the URL instead of the body of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the Cypher query in the `content` property rather than `query`:

```
HTTP.call('POST', 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher',
  {headers:{"Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"},
  content: "MATCH (n:unit) RETURN n LIMIT 25"},
  function (error, result) {
  // callback function here, not shown for brevity...
});
```

In fact `content` (or data) [is for the request body](http://docs.meteor.com/#http_call) while query is the query string to use in the URL -like in GET requests.